# the choice of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ for uniform continuous derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D\subseteq\mathbb {R}$ and let $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be a uniform continuous function, that is,
$$\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists\delta>0\,\,\text{such that}\,\,\forall\,x,y\in D$$
we have
$$|y-x|<\delta\,\Longrightarrow\, |f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$.

Now, I also know the derivative of $f$, i.e. $\partial f$ is also uniform continuous, again, we can choose a $\delta*$ depends only on $\epsilon$ works for all $x$, my question is,

How does the $\delta*$ (for the derivative) compare to the $\delta$ (for the original function), can $\delta*$ be expressed in term of $\delta$?

Comment: First thought: Note that uniform continuity does not imply differentiability, so going from $\delta$ to $\delta^*$ (i.e. $\delta^*(\epsilon) \le g( \delta(\epsilon))$ for some $g$) seems unlikely, since this would hold without knowledge of the differentiability of the function. To go in the other direction is, of course, trivial.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 you mean, it is unlikely $\delta^*$ can be expressed in term of $\delta$?Then when I write the proof, is it enough to simply use a different notation to indicate the choice of $\delta$ is different? Like the $\delta^*$ I used here.

Comment: Notice also that if $f$ is uniformly continuous then there isn't a unique $\delta(\epsilon)$ that you can choose. Indeed for any $\delta(\epsilon)$ that satisfies the condition, every $0<\delta'(\epsilon)<\delta(\epsilon)$  satisfies again the condition.

Comment: @mrprottolo First, I don't understand why " there isn't a unique $\delta(\epsilon)$ that you can choose. "

Comment: Second, I don't understand why $\delta'(\epsilon)<\delta(\epsilon)$?

Comment: The fact that a $\delta'(\epsilon)$, such that $0<\delta'(\epsilon)<\delta(\epsilon)$, satisfies again the condition is the reason why there isn't a unique $\delta(\epsilon)$. Because you can replace $\delta(\epsilon)$ with $\delta'(\epsilon)$

Comment: the thing I do not understand is that why $\delta'(\epsilon)$ has to be smaller than $\delta(\epsilon)$?

Comment: why can't $\delta'(\epsilon)\ge \delta(\epsilon)$?